# Rounding in C Preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am defining some values in the preprocessor. e.g.

```
#define a 1000
#define b 0.5*a
```

When I try to use b in a place where integer is needed I get an error. I don't want to cast `b` always in my code and do it once in the `#define` line, is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#define a 1000
#define b (a/2)
```

Comment: ok, what if a and b are defined and want to define c as a/b ?

Comment: Then you could write: #define c (a/b)

Answer (score 3):

```
#define b ((int)(a * 0.5))
```